# Windows cannot find scrapy file in dir

Tags: python, windows, scrapy

So I got a simple runner script that will use Popen to call the spider.
The runner script is as follows:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import time
def runSpider():
    p = Popen(["scrapy", "crawl", "spider1"], 
        cwd="C:\Users\Kasutaja\Desktop\scrapyTest")
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    time.sleep(15)

runSpider()
```

The directory is like this:

```
 -----scrapyTest: 
 --------------------scrapyTest[folder]: spider[folder], items.py, pipelines.py, settings.py
 --------------------runner.py
 --------------------scrapy.cfg
```

The spider runs perfectly from the dir: **C:\Users\Kasutaja\Desktop\scrapyTest** when I run it from the cmd line.

When I run my runner.py script I get:

> The system cannot find the file specified

EDIT:

After changing the Popen to this:

```
p = Popen(["C:\Users\Kasutaja\Desktop\scrapyTest","scrapy", "crawl", "spider1"])
```

I get the error:

```
    C:\Users\Kasutaja\Desktop\scrapyTest>python runner.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 13, in <module>
    runSpider()
  File "runner.py", line 8, in runSpider
    p = Popen(["C:\Users\Kasutaja\Desktop\scrapyTest","scrapy", "crawl", "spider
1"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

If it matters, I have admin rights.
I have also tried now, running the script with cmd specifically opened from start menu and with admin rights, but still get the same error.

Comment: Could you provide a full traceback?

Comment: What happens if you put the runner.py script into the "C:\Users\Kasutaja\Desktop\scrapyTest" and run it from there?

Comment: The script is there, as when I call the scrapy crawl spider1 command from cmd-line also from there, it works. just not by calling it through runner.py

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to
>   cwd before it is executed. **Note that this directory is not considered
>   when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path
>   relative to cwd.** *(Emphasis mine)*

to me that means you have to do something like

```
Popen(["C:\Users\Kasutaja\Desktop\scrapyTest\scrapy", "crawl", "spider1"])
```

this will execute a program `scrapy` with arguments `crawl` and `spider1`

Comment: Thank you, but now I get Windows Error[5]: access is denied